# Video not working in FF on OSX

Tags: html, macos, firefox, video

Any ideeas is Firefox on OSX has some known issues with html5 videos? I tried and added my video in 3 formats(mp4, ogg & webm) but it still doesn't work.

```
<video width="853" height="510" controls poster="img/video_first_screen_SEO.jpg">
    <source src="video/www.rankxpress.com-seo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/www.rankxpress.com-seo.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/www.rankxpress.com-seo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
</video>
```

And [here](http://rankxpressdesignandmarketing.com/Rankxpress_2014/new/index.html) is my work on progress.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox on OSX does not yet support H264/MP4 video, hence it will fall back to webm and/or ogv.

However, your `.webm` and `.ogv` are served with the wrong media type, as the Web Console tells you:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/plain" is not supported. Load of media resource http://rankxpressdesignandmarketing.com/Rankxpress_2014/new/video/www.rankxpress.com-seo.webm failed.

You'll have to make your web server serve the video files with a `video/webm` and/or `video/ogg` MIME type. See [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Since you appear to use the Apache webserver, placing the following in a `.htaccess` *might* work:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg
```

Comment: But how should I declar them than? :| I even tried now with type="video/ogg; codecs=dirac, speex"

Comment: Your web server needs to serve the files with the correct MIME type.